# Is there a way in Cucumber Java to read/parse multiple feature files and generate a single feature file?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to write a program that reads multiple feature files, parses them and club/generate into a single feature file. I have been looking into Cucumber Gherkin GitHub source code but couldn't really find if there is a way to do so. Could anyone please throw some light?

Example:

Input feature files:

Feature1.feature

---

Scenario: First scenario

Give A

When B

Then C

Feature2.feature

---

Scenario: Second scenario

Give D

When E

Then F

---

---

Output feature file:

Feature3.feature

Scenario: Combined scenario

Give A

When B

Then C

Given D

When E

Then F

Tried creation objects with GherkinDocument, GherkinParser, GherkinParser.Builder classes but couldn't find methods to generate output feature file.